# Check Keyboard Input Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyevent

I was wondering if instead of doing this

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        Console.WriteLine("The A key is down.");
}
```

I could set up a bool method and do this:

```
if(KeyDown(Keys.A))
// do whatever here
```

I've been sitting here for ages trying to figure out how to do it. But I just can't wrap my head around it.

In case you were wondering, my plan is to call the bool inside a different method, to check for input.

Comment: Always use the events. You are about to make a serious UI programming mistake.

Comment: I shared an `IsKeyDonw` method which lets you check if a key is down. The method may be useful like [`MouseButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx), [`MousePosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx), [`ModifierKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`IsKeyLocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But surely you should not forget correct ways of getting input. Just use these methods when you need.

Answer (score 2):

Since you usually want to perform an action immediately after pressing a key, usually using a `KeyDown` event is enough.

But in some cases I suppose you want to check if a specific key is down in middle of a some process, so you can use [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method this way:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
public const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState((int)key) & KEY_PRESSED);
}
```

You should know, each time you check the key state using for example `IsKeyDown(Keys.A)` the method returns `true` if the key is pressed at the moment of checking the state.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
private bool KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e, Keys key)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == key)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Then use it like

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(KeyCode(e, Keys.A))
    {
        //do whatever
    }
    else if (KeyCode (e, Keys.B))
    {
         //do whatever
    }
    // so on and so forth
}
```

HTH.

---

**As per your comment**
the following code will work. But remember that this is not recommended for object oriented design.

```
class FormBase: Form
{
    private Keys keys;

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         keys = e.KeyCode;
    }   

    protected bool KeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        if(keys == key)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now derive your `Form` classes from this class instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class and use the function as below:

```
public class MyForm: FormBase
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(KeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            //do something when 'A' is pressed
        }
        else if (KeyDown(Keys.B))
        {
            //do something when 'B' is pressed
        }
        else
        {
            //something else
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I wish to eliminate the need for the KeyEventArgs though,... instead of If(KeyCode(e,Keys.A), I'd prefer if (KeyCode(Keys.A))