# Is there a method that could check for keyboard input without using event?

Tags: c#, winforms, input, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating a game for a personal project and I'm using Windows Form. I want to check every few milliseconds if the user clicks on the arrow keys. I tried Keyboard.IsKeyDown() but it doesn't seem to be available in Windows Forms. So is there another way of doing it?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fps = new Timer();
        fps.Interval = 30;
        fps.Tick += Fps_Tick;
        fps.Start();
    }

    private void Fps_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int X = playerBlue.Location.X;
        int Y = playerBlue.Location.Y;

        if (((KeyEventArgs)e).KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            X += 2;
            playerBlue.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        }

        if (((KeyEventArgs)e).KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            X -= 2;
            playerBlue.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not using key events?

Comment: Since you usually want to perform an action immediately after pressing a key, usually using a `KeyDown` event is enough. But in some cases I suppose you want to check if a specific key is down in middle of a some process. I shared an `IsKeyDonw` method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39208694/3110834) which lets you check if a key is down. The method may be useful like other static methods such as `MouseButtons`, `MousePosition`, `ModifierKeys` or `IsKeyLocked`. But surely you should not forget correct ways of getting input. Just use these methods when you need

Comment: I feel it's a bit different i'll add the code

Comment: No it's not different. First choice is using `KeyDown` or other keyboard events. Also if you want to check is a specific key is down, you can use the method which I shared in duplicate question.