# How to parse the keys (i.e ., ModifierKey+Down) in UI automation?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, ui-automation

I have created the project for UI Automation (record the key and mouse events and playback it). All are working expected other than the below use case,

1. Record the UI action with (Shift+Down) key. I could save it in my script file as ModifierKey (shift) and KeyCode(Down) properties.

but i don't know, how to make work these combination in PlayBack? and How to notify that "Shift" key is in pressed state?

**my sample code:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte key, byte scan, int flags, int extraInfo);

public static void KeyDown(KeyArgs key)
{
    keybd_event(ParseKey(key), 0, 0, 0);
}

static byte ParseKey(KeyArgs key)
{
    // Alt, Shift, and Control need to be changed for API function to work with them
    Keys keyValue;
    if (key.Modifiers != Keys.None)
        keyValue = (key.Modifiers | key.KeyCode);
    else
        keyValue = key.KeyCode;
    switch (keyValue)
    {
        case Keys.Alt:
            return (byte)18;
        case Keys.Control:
            return (byte)17;
        case Keys.Shift:
            return (byte)16;
        default:
            return (byte)keyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified code as below

"keybd_event(ParseKey(key), 0x0001 | 0, 0, 0)"

Its working as expected.

Comment: [Check Keyboard Input Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208694/3110834)