# How can I check to see if a specific key is pressed as a boolean?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know that I can have a key press event like this-

```
private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    //Pressing Control + N
    if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N)) MessageBox.Show("e");
}
```

But is there any way I can check to see whether the space key is pressed in a different function? I know that I can check to see if the CTRL key is being pressed, like this

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it like this?

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Space)
```

Comment: Usually using `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` event and using some flags is enough for you. But in case that you need another solution like `ModifierKeys` or `IsKeyLocked`, you can use [`GetKeyState`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208694/3110834).

Comment: you can use the Keyboard.IsKeyDown Method [link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown(v=vs.110).aspx)